# Не работает timeout в disnake.py discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord, disnake

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы команда правильно понимала мой запрос, а именно чтобы я мог вводить `>мут @username 10 сек нарушил` или `>мут @username 10 мин нарушил` или `>мут @username 10 час нарушил`, а бот должен отвечать `✅ Участник @username замучен на 10 секунд нарушил` и так далее. Но у меня работают только секунды, а остальные виды времени бот не распознает. Также работает так: `>мут @username 10 нарушил`. Помогите, пожалуйста. Вот код:

```
@bot.command(aliases=["Мут"])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def мут(ctx, member: disnake.Member, time=None, *, reason=None):
    if member != None:
        if time != None:
            t = humanfriendly.parse_timespan(time)
            await member.timeout(until = disnake.utils.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=t), reason=reason)
            if reason != None:
                embed = disnake.Embed(
                    description = f'✅ Учасник {member.mention} успешно замучен на {time} {reason}',
                    color=0xc80005)        
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                embed = disnake.Embed(
                    description = f'**✅ Учасник {member.mention}** замучен на {time}',
                    color=0xc80005)        
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            embed = disnake.Embed(
                description = f'❌ {ctx.author}  укажите  время  наказания',
                color=0xc80005)        
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = disnake.Embed(
            description = f'❌ {ctx.author}  укажите  кого  нужно  наказать',
            color=0xc80005)        
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Вот картинка вывода
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может ли у вас быть одновременно несколько типов времени? Типа 2час20мин

Comment: Я думаю нет так как у стандартных ботов этой функции нету нужно указывать конкретное время без дополнений так сказать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Библиотека `humanfriendly` не поддерживает русские слова типа `мин`, `сек`, `час`.

Поэтому заменяем русские слова на английские с помощью метода `replace()`.

```
@bot.command(aliases=["Мут"])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def мут(ctx, member: disnake.Member, time=None, *, reason=None):
    if member != None:
        if time != None:
            time=time.replace('час','h').replace('мин', 'm').replace('сек', 's')
            t = humanfriendly.parse_timespan(time)
            await member.timeout(until = disnake.utils.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=t), reason=reason)
            if reason != None:
                embed = disnake.Embed(
                    description = f'✅ Учасник {member.mention} успешно замучен на {time} {reason}',
                    color=0xc80005)        
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                embed = disnake.Embed(
                    description = f'**✅ Учасник {member.mention}** замучен на {time}',
                    color=0xc80005)        
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            embed = disnake.Embed(
                description = f'❌ {ctx.author}  укажите  время  наказания',
                color=0xc80005)        
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = disnake.Embed(
            description = f'❌ {ctx.author}  укажите  кого  нужно  наказать',
            color=0xc80005)        
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!

Comment: есть еще вопрос как это обойти? чтобы при указании к примеру `>мут @Horbor 10сек виноват` бот выводил сообщение не так `Учасник @Horbor успешно замучен на **10s** виноват` а вот так: `Учасник @Horbor успешно замучен на **10c** виноват` то есть чтобы были русские слова с - сек и тд

Comment: `time=time.replace('h', 'час').replace('m', 'мин').replace('s', 'сек')` после команды `await member.timeout()`.

Comment: Если помог ответ, проголосуйте, пожалуйста:)

Comment: у меня маленькая репутация я не могу голосовать пока что но огромное вам спасибо! Но когда я сделал как вы сказали то оно работает не совсем правильно давайте я создам новый вопрос чтобы вы поняли про что я говорю